# Conditional part of makefile always evaluating to true

Tags: makefile

I have a legacy makefile based build system that I am trying to make changes to. I am not familiar with make and so was making changes on a trial and error basis.

Not being able to deduce what the problem is I inserted this bit of code in the makefile:

```
ARG1 = GCC
ARG2 = ARM
ifeq($(ARG1),$(ARG2))
$(warning *** WARNING ***)
endif
```

When I run make, I always get the print:

```
   \PathToBuildDirectory\makefile.options:54:*** WARNING ***
```

**NOTE: I am using clearmake with the -C gnu option.**

How or why does the condition evaulate to true?

Answer (score 1):

If it behaves this way for a makefile consisting of only the above content then it's a bug in `clearmake`.  I know that clearmake's emulation of GNU make is incomplete, but this seems pretty simple.

However, since you're already echoing an error wouldn't it be straightforward to also show the values of ARG1 and ARG2?  Maybe they ARE equal.  Maybe one or both are set on the command line.  Maybe elsewhere one or both was assigned with the `override` option.  Maybe clearmake is invoked with the `-e` option and one or both of those variables are set in the environment.

If you show their values, then you'll know.

ETA: Maybe the problem is this: in GNU make you must put a space after the `ifeq`, like this:

```
ifeq ($(ARG1),$(ARG2))
```

If you try your original version with GNU make, you'll get an error:

```
Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

but I guess clearmake just ignores the line without any error messages.

Comment: I put in the code snippet in a generic manner. I even tried this: 

ifeq(ARM,GNU)
$(warning *** WARNING ***)
endif

Now even this produces the print statement in the output! Because the behaviour was so bizzare and unbelievable, I checked the make manual for the syntax of the ifeq statement and did not find an apparent error in the usage.

Any clue what's going wrong?